# Installing RPostgreSQL on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, rpostgresql

When I try on linux in R

```
install.packages('RPostgreSQL')
```

it fails with unspecified errors:

```
  Warning message:
  In install.packages("RPostgreSQL") :
     installation of package ‘RPostgreSQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to solve problem with:

```
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-8.4 for postgresql version 8.4.
```

but it doesn't seems to work.

```
    sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

I have PostgreSQL 9.1.11 version.

Comment: You do *not* need ` postgresql-server-dev-8.4` which is for *server-side development*.  You want to build a *client*. Install `libpq-dev`, or the version variant for your server variant.

Comment: If `apt-get` is not yet present you should probably take a step back and start with some basic tutorials to Debian and Ubuntu package management.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Read the configure log.

You most likely "merely" forgot to read the README and DESCRIPTION and other documentation telling you to do

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

We develop this on, inter alia, Debian/Ubuntu systems so can be more than sure that it works there.

Comment: thank you for help, but unfortunately this command gives me rezult: 
sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: If apt-get is not yet present you should probably take a step back and start with some basic tutorials to Debian and Ubuntu package management.

Comment: As I told you twice already, step back and deal with that. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: I'm sorry for misleadings. But it seems, that I have another Linux version and this command is not suitable for me. 
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46 UTC 2013

Comment: In which case you will have to learn about the equivalent CentOS command (`yum`) and how to install the PostgreSQL header and library for CentOS.