# Installing RPostgres Library in Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, installation, rpostgres

I am trying to install the RPostgres library in R but I am using JupyterLab on Google Cloud Platform. I have found several suggestions on github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres, but none of them include information when working with Google Cloud Notebooks.

I continue to receive the error that RPostgres had "non-zero exit status" even after trying to install the package from the source code after placing it into the correct folder on JupyterLab:

```
install.packages("MyPath/RPostgres_1.3.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type='source')
```

I receive the same error message RPostgres had "non-zero exit status". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you first need to install "libpq-dev" as this is a prerequisite as per [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202222/14733669). Follow the steps below to apply this in a Google Cloud Notebook.

- Open a terminal in your JupyterLab and execute `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

  [image]
- Open a R notebook, install Rpostgres using `install.packages("RPostgres")`

  [image]
- Run `library()` and check if it was installed properly

  [image]

Please take note that the machine I used for testing is created in AI Platform -> Notebooks -> R instance.